# Angular app unable to compile when using a jQuery plugin (Foundation 6 accordion)

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, zurb-foundation

I have an Angular 5 project with a [Foundation 6 accordion menu](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion-menu.html) (not to be confused with a regular accordion).

```
<ul id="sidenav-list" class="vertical menu accordion-menu" data-accordion-menu data-multi-open="false">
  <li [ngClass]="navSections.personalAndIncome.statusClass">
  <a (click)="handleUpdateClassesOnSectionNavigate('personalAndIncome')" data-toggle="tab" title="Personal and Income">
    <span [ngClass]="navSections.personalAndIncome.navIconClass"></span>
    <span class="round-tabs one">Personal &amp; Income</span>
  </a>

  <!-- Personal and Income Pages -->
  <ul id="personalPages" class="menu vertical nested" [ngClass]="navSections.personalAndIncome.expandedClass">

    <li>
      <a [ngClass]="navSections.personalAndIncome.pages.profile.statusClass" routerLink="personal-and-income/profile" title="Profile">
        <span class="round-tabs one">Profile</span>
        <span [ngClass]="navSections.personalAndIncome.pages.profile.statusIconClass"></span>
      </a>
    </li>

    ...
  </ul>
</ul>
```

And in my controller I have a very simple ngOnInit function

```
ngOnInit() {
  $('#sidenav-list').foundation('down', $('#personalPages'));    
}
```

This code runs fine and works perfectly - the personalPages sub list is expanded as expected. However I get the following error from ng serve.

> ERROR in src/app/form/nav-components/side-nav/side-nav.component.ts(64,43): error TS2345: Argument of type 'JQuery' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Options'.
>   Type 'JQuery' has no properties in common with type 'Options'.

It looks like TS is using the interface for regular accordions for this call on an accordion menu element (regular accordion docs are [here](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion.html), note that the second argument to foundation() is an $options object for regular accordion but the docs say a jQuery object for the accordion menu)

Comment: As per the doc the correct signature is `var elem = new Foundation.AccordionMenu(element, options);` but you are using `$('#personalPages')` in place of option which is not a jquery element.

Comment: Shouldnt this be  `$('#sidenav-list').foundation($('#personalPages'),'down'); `

Comment: Niladri I think you're looking at the wrong part of the doc. See here: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion-menu.html#down

$('#element').foundation('down', $target); where $target is specified as jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The type `<HTMLElement>` *cannot* be used with jQuery, *because it's not an HTML element*, it's a jQuery element: that is, a wrapper *around* an `HTMLElement`.**

This gave me headaches too, when I tried to use a jQuery plugin (a datepicker) with my Angular app.

---

First, make sure the jquery types are installed:

```js
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

So you can import jQuery in your component/service, and have `$` available:

```js
import 'jquery';
```

---

Next, make sure both jQuery and your foundation plugin are added to your Angular app, for Angular-cli you can use the `angular-cli.json` file, and there should be something comparable for non-cli Angular:

```js
...
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../some/path/to/foundation.js"
],
...
```

---

Third, to skip the whole `HTMLElement` error stuff, wrap the selector in `(...)` and give it type `any`:

```js
// Use either this
(<any> $('#sidenav-list')).foundation(...);

// Or this
($('#sidenav-list') as any).foundation(...);
```

You may have to wrap `$('#personalPages')` too, but I'm not sure.

---

Now you *should* be able to succesfully serve and/or build your app.

Comment: Casting the sidenav-list element as any did the trick. Thank you! Points awarded!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my point of view. The function is expecting a string but you are passing a Jquery object. Foundation itself is already based on jQuery so you dont need to add a jQuery object. You only need to specify the target as string. So you should do this way

```
ngOnInit() {
  $('#sidenav-list').foundation('down', '#personalPages');    
}
```

Comment: Hmm - doing it this way compiled without error but the section did not expand... when I pass through the jQuery object it does expand.

Comment: Oh and I didn't notice at first, this throws a JS error: ERROR TypeError: t.parentsUntil is not a function
    at e.value (foundation.min.js:1)
    at w.fn.init.e [as foundation] (foundation.min.js:3). Looks like Foundation is expecting some sort of object.

Comment: Can you update your post and paste the error ? Or just a screenshot ?

Comment: Maybe you can use the non mim version of foundation for debug

Comment: ERROR TypeError: t.parentsUntil is not a function at e.value (foundation.min.js:1) at w.fn.init.e [as foundation] (foundation.min.js:3)

Answer (score 0):

The point is the compiler use `typescript definition` files to compile your application using typescript. so once you use `jquery` plugin, you should lookup for the `.d.ts` type file of it.

I did some research and i found the type file you need.

[npm foundation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/foundation)

After you follow the installation steps, make sure that you use the right version of the `js` plugin that matches the `@types` file.